# PHP- Store in a session variable the name of the clicked link

Tags: php, session

I have a list with many links. These options are generated by a mysql query. My idea is when I click on one of the options (these options link to menuestaciones.php), I can store in my session variable, eg `$_SESSION [ 'station']`, the name of the clicked link

```
<div class="listadoestaciones">
            <?php while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($estacionesclientes)):; ?>
                <p> <a href="menuestacion.php"><?php echo $row1['lnStationName']; ?></a>
                </p>


            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
```

For example,the next code,my session variable is `$_SESSION['clickedlink']`:

```
<a href="menuestacion.php" name="link1">
page1
</a>

<a href="menuestacion.php" name="link2">
page2</a>

<a href="menuestacion.php" name="link3">
page3</a>
```

If I click on page3 , `$_SESSION['clickedlink']="link3"`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Either you do it using AJAX or you set the session value on the target site

Comment: @Bub I need store this value because in **menuestacion.php**  i have to do query  mysql with this value. not is possible implement this by PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are totally confused. You are combining client side script (used to track clicks) with server side script ($_SESSION). There are two ways to tackle your issue here, either use AJAX and alter sessions by parsing links or another way is to save it using sessionStorage in Javascript (recommended 'cause it is very fast and user friendly).

Comment: this is not an answer, better to put this info as comment

Comment: @Insomania *"Answers should add to the community knowledge on the subject"* and I am pretty sure this is an answer